# Reference Request: Compact subgroups of p-adic Reductive Groups

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

First, I'd like to understand what the compact open subgroups of an inner form of $G := GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ are, and how they relate to the compact open subgroups of $G$.

Second, I'd like to know where I can read about this for other reductive groups $G$.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question might be too advanced to have a good chance of getting an answer on this site. Maybe you should wait a week or two and then pose it on Math Overflow, explaining that you got no help here.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks! I actually did post it there and got some helpful remarks. I'm glad you think it's a reasonable thing to ask on MO though. I'm always scared of asking something there and being told to take it to MSE.

Comment: Oh, you just gotta develop a thick skin. I’ve made a fool of myself often enough on MO.